# Modules in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In L3 i managed to make a module system where i was able to install/uninstall modules from an admin area.

```
if(!Bundle::exists($name))
    {
        // Load the bundle
        // If a routes file exists then we'll assume it handles routes of it's own name.
        // Remember, if you need it to handle a custom route you should manually add
        // the bundle in application/bundles.php.
        Bundle::register($name, array(
                'handles'   => File::exists($path.DS.'routes.php') ? $name : null,
                'location'  => 'path: '.$path,
                'auto'      => true)
        );

        // autobundle is already in the loop that's starting bundles so we
        // can't let the normal mechanism start it. We'll start it here.
        Bundle::start($name);
    }
```

How i can do it in L4? L4 it looks very different for me, i started using L3 2 months ago (first framework)

Comment: I can not give you full instructions, so I wont compose an answer, but "Bundles" are now called "packages".

Comment: I never used composer, and laravel 3 was the first framework that i tried. In laravel 4 i can't find a way to start/stop "packages"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or if you still want modules that are more app specific you can check out my tutorial at: http://creolab.hr/2013/05/modules-in-laravel-4/

I'll expand on that article soon to explain how to build a simple interface to activate/deactivate these modules.

Comment: Great article, if you can post how to activate/deactivate packages will be great

Answer (score 0):

Bundles are now Packages, which are actually libraries of reusable PHP code stored on various locations and indexed by [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) (installable with [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/)).

In order to do Laravel based package development you'll need to checkout this documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/packages which should help you out.